# How to provide common web interface to various R and python programs?

Tags: python, r, user-interface, web

We have a large, interactive R program that we would like to interface with Shiny. There is a small Python program we would also like to create an interface for alongside it. There are no dependencies between the two sets of code, but as a research institute we'd like to provide a common interface for the two programs might be accessed by the same users. What is a good way to go about it? Is it better to consolidate under python/Django and use rpy2, or make system calls to the python program through R's Shiny interface? Are there better alternatives, or recommended practices?

Comment: If have 90% of your code in R , a shiny interface is a better choice. I would call the python using `system` or shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django would be an overkill.

**rpy2** is a good option for small modules containing simpler methods

**flask** is another good option for python's side. Programmers can transmit files or even build simple web-interfaces. *I prefer this method.* Tell your students/collegues to define fixed APIs and response format [JSON/XML] and even a new scholar wouldn't have to spend times thinking about how to make it work. Just tell him the APIs and work with it just like Alchemy etc interfaces.

**Shiny** is a good option for building web-interfaces on R side. A quick tutorial that works. http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson2/